# SQLite - Count и More Than

Tags: sql, select

Не удается правильно построить селект

```
Integer indicatedAmount = 2;
String sql = "SELECT customer_id, count(id) as count_of_orders from orders group by customer_id";
```

Нужно что-то вроде:

```
String sql = "SELECT customer_id, count(id) AS count_of_orders FROM orders 
WHERE count_of_orders > 2 GROUP BY customer_id";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  customer_id,
  count(id) as count_of_orders
from orders
group by customer_id
having count(id) > 2;
```